# Como colocar uma área clicável num pedaço de uma imagem?

Tags: html

Eu tenho este código no meu site:

```
.fixed-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}


<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">
    <img class="fixed-background" 
    src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/cats-animals-kittens-background.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Eu queria que apenas o olho do gato ficasse clicável, mas também que a imagem se ajustasse ao tamanho do *browser* (largura e altura), ou seja, a imagem tem de bater com o *top*, o *bottom*, o *right* e o *left* seja qual for o tamanho do *browser*.

Tentei com o `map` e `area` mas não consegui porque a imagem não tem tamanho fixo. Como posso fazer isso?

[Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6rxhp6f/1/)

Comment: Há muito tempo atrás o Dreamweaver tinha uma ferramenta para criar estes mapas clicáveis sobre uma imagem. Era bem fácil, vc seleciona com o mouse a área e pronto. Talvez te ajude.

Comment: Obrigado @rochasdv vi agora que o gimp também tem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reutilizando o [`map` que o OnoSendai postou,](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88734/20615) você pode adicionar a biblioteca [jQuery RWD Image Maps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps) para redimencionar automaticamente as coordenadas de sua imagem.

> jQuery RWD mapas de imagem
>   Permite mapas de imagem para ser usado em um projeto ágil recalculando a área coordenadas para coincidir com o tamanho da imagem real.

Ficaria assim o seu exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
 
 $('area').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('alt') + ' clicked');
 });
});
```

```css
.fixed-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/master/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/cats-animals-kittens-background.jpg" 
       usemap="#Map" 
       id='imagem'
       class="fixed-background" 
       />

  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area href="#" onClick="alert('Olho esquerdo');" 
          shape="poly" coords="339,207,311,221,319,247,352,258,374,247,380,214,362,207" />
    <area href="#" onClick="alert('Olho direito');" 
          shape="poly" coords="369,305,327,320,325,350,338,382,357,383,384,369,395,343,389,314" />
  </map>
</div>
```

Teste o ajuste de tamanho [neste exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/yqdu7syx/2/) e veja se lhe atende.

Comment: É isto mesmo, obrigado :) +1

Comment: @randrade olá. havia possibilidades de adaptar para 100% da imagem e quando eu der um submit em algum form, enviar a localização marcada...

Answer (score 15):

A imagem original não precisa possuir tamanhos definidos - mas as áreas do mapa necessitam de valores absolutos.

Entretanto, você pode recalcular o tamanho da imagem via propriedade CSS `Zoom`, e o mapa respeitará a definição. Exemplo:

```js
var larguraImg = document.getElementById('imagem').offsetWidth;

var recalcZoom = function ()
{
  var larguraPai = $("#imageContainer").width();
  
  var zoom = larguraPai / larguraImg;
  
  console.log('larguraImg: ' + larguraImg);
  console.log('larguraPai: ' + larguraPai);
  console.log('zoom: ' + zoom);
  
  $("#imagem").css('zoom', zoom);
  
};

$("#imageContainer").resize(function() {
  recalcZoom();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  recalcZoom();
});

recalcZoom();
```

```css
#imageContainer {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='imageContainer'>

  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/cats-animals-kittens-background.jpg" 
       usemap="#Map" 
       id='imagem'
       />

  <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area href="#" onClick="alert('Olho esquerdo');" 
          shape="poly" coords="339,207,311,221,319,247,352,258,374,247,380,214,362,207" />
    <area href="#" onClick="alert('Olho direito');" 
          shape="poly" coords="369,305,327,320,325,350,338,382,357,383,384,369,395,343,389,314" />
  </map>
</div>
```

Para o seu requisito inicial:

> [...] que a imagem se ajustasse ao tamanho do browser [...]

Você pode proceder da seguinte maneira:

- Detecte eventos de resize (no meu exemplo utilizei jQuery);
- Recalcule o fator de zoom.

Comment: Não funciona, porque eu tenho a imagem sem tamanho fixo, vê na pergunta, editei.

Comment: @JorgeB. solução alterada para permitir resizing da imagem via zoom.

Comment: Continua a não funcionar porque falta que a imagem se adapte ao tamanho do browser. (largura e altura)

Comment: Pratico e simples e ainda fácil de adaptar para algo sem jQuery.